# How can I read params object from a react component

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a rails controller to redirect user on another one with params

```
 redirect_to :controller => 'courses', :action => 'new', :redirected => true
```

On my courses controller I have a react component defined on a jsx.erb file, is it possible to access the params object in react, to do something like

```
var myvar = "<%= params[:redirected]%>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access `var myvar = "<%= params[:redirected]%>"`

Be care that it should be written outside of `$(document).ready()` or `window.load`

and update your controller as well

```
redirect_to new_course_path(:redirected => true)
```

Comment: I am getting a undefined local variable or method `params'

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks